# How does pointer type casting work in c

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I understand that in c, a pointer points to a memory address. In the following code

```
char *cp;
someType *up; // Assuming that someType is a union of size 16 bytes
cp = sbrk(nu * sizeof(someType)); 

// Here is what confuses me
up = (someType *)cp;
```

According to this link http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Pointers_and_arrays

1. If cp points to an address of 0x1234, so 0x1234 should be the beginning of the newly allocated memory, right?
2. So when "cp" is casted to a pointer to someType and assigned to "up", it actually says "up" is a pointer that points to 0x1234, assumes in 32-bits system, each memory address takes 4 bytes, a someType object will use 4 memory address to store its value, so the addresses 0x1234, 0x1235, 0x1236, 0x1237 collectively store a someType object, is this correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I really think you could've asked that more clearly. Don't you think showing showing what the heck `Header` is would be helpful?

Comment: @JonathanWood The code is from malloc() in K&R, Header is just a union  indicating the size and a pointer to the next Header. I just assume it is 16 byte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pointer type casting doesn't do anything at the machine level.  The value in memory is still just a plain old value in memory.

At the language level, that value is used as an address.  In other words it is often used as the value passed to operations that require memory locations, such as the assembly "load" operation.

At the language level, extra constructs are added to the machine operations, and one of those "extras" are data types.  The compiler is responsible for checking if type-rule violations exist, but at run time there is not such a constraint.

As a result, the cast does nothing at run time, but at compile time it directs the compiler to not emit an error as the type of the pointer's value will now be considered a compatible type to the variable holding the address.

Comment: Converting a pointer of one type to a pointer of another type might or might not do anything at the machine level. That depends on the implementation. Some C implementations have different kinds of pointers.

Comment: True, but that is how C is implemented on some systems.  The machines themselves don't carry around a type system, so casting _still_ doesn't do anything at the machine level.  It's just that some languages implement casting in less-optimum ways (probably to obtain some other benefit, like better debugging or RTTI).

Comment: In some implementations, converting a pointer of one type to a pointer to another type requires collecting an offset and a base and performing some arithmetic. In some implementations, converting a pointer of one type to a pointer of another type requires moving (or removing or adding) bits that indicate the byte within a word. Converting pointers in these implementations does result in machine-level operations.

Comment: I'm not arguing about machine-level operations.  Everything with a side effect results in machine-level operations.  I'm talking about a parallel machine-level "type" tracking system, which to my knowledge isn't present on any hardware device (although the JVM is getting close to having a parallel "type" register for the references stored in the registers).

Comment: The statement in this answer “Pointer type casting doesn't do anything at the machine level” is not true for all C implementations.

Comment: @EdwinBuck Yes I understand the casting does not change the memory address, but the memory addresses, as Vaughn Cato said, from 0x1234 to 0x1243 do store the value of Header, right?

Comment: Yes and no.  0x1234 is an address, nothing more.  It might have data that satisfies the needs of a Header struct, or it might not.  The cast tells the compiler to treat this address like an address that satisfies the needs of a Header struct.  This satisfies the compiler's type checking routines, but actually doesn't have a strong requirement for the machine to do anything.   The assignment does require the machine to do something, so the assignment will likely create a memory move operation, in pseduo-English "store cp's value into up", but the cast is often optimized to nothing.

Comment: You two are talking past each other.  Eric is correct, because there really have been machines (the original Cray comes to mind) on which not all C pointers had the same machine-level representation; casting from (say) `char *` to `int *` on such a machine required the compiler to emit code to change the representation.  However, Edwin is also correct, because *even on such machines* there were only a few pointer representations (compare to the countable infinity of C types) and the hardware did not enforce the C type system except by accident.

Answer (score 4):

Even on a 32-bit system, a memory address typically refers to a single byte, not four.  So your `Header` will be covering the 16 memory addresses between 0x1234 and 0x1243.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

`cp` points to the beginning of the newly allocated memory.

However, `up` will contain the same address as `cp`. Note it is bad form to try and assign a pointer from one type to a different type without "casting" it first - just to tell the compiler you really meant to do such a dangerous thing.

Typically assigning between types can cause all kinds of problems - as a result compilers will throw warnings if you do this without casting. The casting, however, doesn't actually have any effect on the program code itself - it is more a method of the programmer telling the compiler they really meant what they did.

---

By the way, the pointer `up` is allocated on the stack in your function. Assigning a value to `up` actually places the value in the memory location on the stack. So by assigning `cp` to `up` you are merely copying the value of the pointer in `cp` to the location in the stack assigned to `up`. There is nothing placed into the memory allocated by the `sbrk()` call.

Answer (score 1):

> If cp points to a address of 0x1234, so 0x1234 should be the beginning of the newly allocated memory, right?

Right.

> So when cp is casted to a pointer to Header and assigned to up, it actually says up is a pointer that points to 0x1234, assumes in 32-bits system, each memory address takes 4 bytes, a Header object will use 4 memory address to store its value, so the addresses 0x1234, 0x1235, 0x1236, 0x1237 collectively store a Header object, is this correct?

Wrong.  C is strictly byte addressed.  The `Header` object will occupy addresses `0x1234` through `0x1234 + sizeof(Header) - 1`, inclusive, whatever `sizeof(Header)` is (perhaps 16 in this case).  To confuse the issue, adding 1 to any pointer increments its numeric value by the `sizeof` whatever it points to, so it is the case that `up + 1` points beyond the end of allocated memory.  However `cp + 1` points to the second byte in the representation of the header object, whatever that is.  (`sizeof(char)` is 1 *by definition*.)

---

This has nothing to do with your question, but I must warn you that calling `sbrk` with a nonzero argument *will* cause your program to crash at some indefinite point after the next call to `malloc`, `realloc` or `free`, and that nearly all standard library functions are allowed to call those functions "under the hood".  If you want to make a large allocation directly from the operating system, use `mmap`.

Comment: Could the addresses Header covering be from 0x1234 to 0x1234 + sizeof(Header) -1 as @Vaughn Cato says?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, remember that a pointer is an *abstraction* of a memory address; do not assume a one-to-one correspondence between a pointer value and a physical location in RAM.  Pointers also have type semantics associated with them; adding 1 to a pointer value advances it to point to the next *object* of the pointed-to type:

```
char *cp;
int *ip;
struct huge *hp;

cp = cp + 1; // advances cp to the address of the next char (1 byte)
ip = ip + 1; // advances ip to the address of the next int (anywhere
             // from 2 to 8 bytes depending on the architecture)
hp = hp + 1; // advances hp to the address of the next struct huge (however
             // many bytes struct huge takes up)
```

This is exactly how array indexing works; the expression `a[i]` is treated as `*(a + i)`; you offset `i` *elements* of whatever size from the base address, not `i` bytes.

As far as the cast is concerned...

A pointer to `char` is a different, incompatible type than a pointer to `Header`.  They may have different sizes and representations depending on the underlying architecture.  Because of this, the language won't allow an implicit conversion of one to the other through a simple assignment; you must use a cast to convert the rhs value to the type expected by the lhs.