# Effect of casting in a C program

Tags: c, casting

I somehow understand the idea about casting, but still have the following questions about it, when we cast a variable from one type to another:

1. Does casting change the actual data type generally? Like eg. if we have `char *name ="james"` and we cast the char pointer ==> `int *name = (int *) name`
2. Do the types of all fields (members) also change in case of a structure data type in C? I.e. if we have a `struct student {int id, char *name}` and there is a pointer to an instance of struct student and type cast it to another type, do the fields also change?

Comment: You cannot cast variables. You cast values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does pointer type casting work in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18255651/how-does-pointer-type-casting-work-in-c)

Comment: Casting in C is a rather complex topic with lots of special rules and could easily create bugs or problems in case you aren't aware of them. It's important to know that we can't wildly cast between any one type or another. For example your `(int*)name` cast would result in undefined behavior bugs if we were to de-reference that pointer as an integer, while the original data is actually a character array.

Comment: Similarly, there are special rules when casting a struct pointer to a pointer corresponding to the type of its first member, and vice versa. To address all of the special casting rules  would require a very long, in-depth answer so possibly that's too complex a topic for SO. So it might be better to ask a single specific question about a certain kind of cast, rather than casting in general.

Comment: Try to understand that "casting" is the programmer telling the compiler how the programmer wishes to deal with the bits and bytes in memory. The programmer takes responsibility for coding in accordance with rules. The compiler does its best to create an executable (a binary) that the programmer has specified in code. The executable doesn't "see" anything special; it is a series of machine instructions manipulating bits and bytes. Casting is used when a programmer takes responsibility for the outcomes. With great power comes great responsibility (to know what you're doing!)

Comment: @Solruhama, "if we have char *name ="james" and we cast the char pointer ==> int *name = (int *) name" is a broken example as that attempts to create 2 different objects with the same identifier.  Once `char *name ="james";` occurs, code cannot change the type of `name` with a new declaration like `int *name = ... (any code);`.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Does casting change the actual data type generally? Like eg. if we have `char *name ="james"` and we cast the char pointer ==> `int *name = (int *) name`

Casting a pointer does not change the memory the pointer points to.

When a pointer, say `p`, is dereferenced, as with `*p`, and used to get a value from memory, the type of the pointer determines how the compiler interprets the memory. If `p` is a `char *`, then using `*p` for its value loads one byte from memory and interprets it as a `char` value. If `p` is an `int *`, then using `*p` for its value loads as many bytes from memory as an `int` uses and interprets them as an `int` value. If `p` is an `int *` and we use `* (char *) p` for its value, then `(char *) p` is a `char *`, so `* (char *) p` loads one byte from memory and interprets it as a `char` value.

Conversely, when using `*p` to store a value to memory, the value will be encoded according to the rules for the `*p` type, and the resulting bytes will be written to memory.

The C standard has rules about which types may be used to access memory that has been established to contain data of another type. If those rules are not followed, the behavior of the program is not defined by the C standard. Using an `int *` converted from a pointer to a `char` in an array of `char` is not one of the defined uses. Nominally, it asks the compiler to interpret the bytes of the array as if they encoded an `int` value, but, because the code is not following the rules of the C standard, the compiler might or might not do that.

> 2. Do the types of all fields (members) also change in case of a structure data type in C? I.e. if we have a `struct student {int id, char *name}` and there is a pointer to an instance of struct student and type cast it to another type, do the fields also change?

Casting a pointer does not change the memory the pointer points to. If you cast a pointer to one structure type to a pointer to another structure type and attempt to access memory with it, it might not work as you desire.

Comment: Great answer. I don't understand why it was downvoted.

Answer (score -1):

From another answer here,

> casting (also called type coercion) does not change the data - the
> underlying bits - but it changes the type, i.e., how those bits are
> interpreted.

In other words, a cast tells the compiler:

"You would think the expression has this type, but I say you to use the expression as it had this different type"

At this point the compiler says "Ok" and compile code to do what you ask for with the cast. Take this example (probably there are better ones):

```
int a,b;
int *p;

a=256;  // does not fit in a single byte
p=&a;   // a pointer to a
b=*p;   // <- now b is 256, the value of a
b=*(char *) p;  // <- now b is 0 (probably)
```

The two assignments to "b" are different. In the first case the compiler nows that p points to integers, so it will move in b 4 or 8 bytes taken from a.

The second assignment, with the cast, tells the compiler to act as p was not a pointer to an integer, but a pointer to a char. And the compiler obeys, and takes only one byte from the value of a (pointed to by p).